# Can you call a JavaScript method based on size of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is any way besides jquery to run JavaScript code based on if the size of a div reaches a certain range of size?

So if the user drags their browser window to be about half of the screen, I want to set a variable value in JavaScript and if they make it full screen again (which makes the div bigger), I want that variable value set back to the original value.

To summarize, there is a JavaScript variable that I want to switch back and forth depending on the size of the div being made smaller or bigger than a certain specified breakpoint size (say 200px).

Is this possible?

Comment: many things are possible so "yes".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` properties.

```
render();

function render() {
    var width = document.getElementById('yourDivID').offsetWidth;
    if (width < 200) {
        foo();
    }
    else {
        bar();
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', render);
```

Comment: you will want to wrap that in a function called `resized` and call that function  `window.onresize = resized;` so that it is called when the browser is resized.